# how to loop over object to make top level keys into getters

Tags: javascript

after having discovered that getters will allow me to solve a problem, I'd like to convert all my top level keys into getters but was wondering how I can do this.  I'm leaning towards looping over Object.keys(obj) as a starting point but would appreciate any method:

```
const obj = {
  parent: {
    child: {
      aunt: this.aunt  // this will be undefined without getters
    }
  },
  aunt: {
    foo: {
      bar: 1
    }
  },...
}
```

into:

```
const obj = {
  get parent() {
    return {
      child: {
        aunt: this.aunt
      }
    }
  },
  get aunt(){
    return {
      foo: {
        bar: 1
      }
    }
  },...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it nicely with a `map` function over the object keys and using the `defineProperty` over a new object:

```
var obj_getters = {}

Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj_getters, key, {
    get: function() { return obj[key] }
  });
})
```

Comment: may I ask why you opted for `map` instead of `forEach` here since there's no return value that I can use as it appears to be purely side effect driven?  Also, thank you so much!

Comment: Nothing special, I have some love for the `map` function, forEach is also nice :P

Comment: for some reason, I could've sworn it worked before but now for the example above, I'm getting undefined as the value for `obj_getters.parent.child.aunt`. I'm not if anyone can confirm this.